# postgres-# \dt Did not find any relations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs

orm.config.ts

```js
import { PostgresConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions';

const config: PostgresConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'Mrinal1996',
  database: 'postgres',
  entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: true,
};

export default config;
```

psql cli

```
postgres-# \dt
Did not find any relations.
```

tag.entity.ts

```js
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

Entity({name:'tags'})
export class TagEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from '@app/app.controller';
import { AppService } from '@app/app.service';
import { TagModule } from '@app/tag/tag.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import  ormconfig  from '@app/ormconfig';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormconfig),TagModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The tables are not getting created automatically and i have kept Sychronization as true.

Please help me to proceed on this.

Comment: 1) In `psql` what does `show search_path;` return? 2) Are you committing the table creation? 3) Look at Postgres log to see what is actually hitting database. You may have to change `log_statement` to `mod` to see the DDL statements. Add information as update to question.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping is wrong, you should try with this config:

> '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'

Instead of:

> '**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'